# Integration constants in geodesic equation for wave equation

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesics, phase-velocity

I am stuck at a following "hello world problem". Let us consider the most common (d'Alembertian) wave equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial^2 x} - \frac{1}{c_0^2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial^2 t} = 0
$$

Now, rewrite it in a fancy manner:

$$
g^{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu} = 0
$$

with the metric tensor

$$g^{\mu \nu} = \left[ \matrix{ -1/c_0^2 & 0 \cr
0 & 1
} \right]$$

Now, I smell some misconception on my side, but one can write two geodesic equations for $x$ and $t$ to obtain a spacetime curve along which a wave is traveling. Since the spacetime is flat, all Christoffel symbols are zero and hence:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}s^2} = 0
$$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2t}{\mathrm{d}s^2} = 0
$$

where $s$ is a path parameter. It immediately follows that

$$
x = c_1 s + c_2
$$

$$
t = c_3 s + c_4
$$

And now what? I would expect that after some manipulations one obtains $x \pm c_0 t = const.$, but I don't know how to set the integration constants. More precisely, what is the reasoning for their choice regarding the original equation, the metric tensor etc.

Comment: I think that you are confusing geodesic curves  with *characteristic* curves. Geodesics in general  have little to do with solutions of the wave equation. You need to find the characteristic curves which will be *null* geodesics.

Comment: @mikestone Sure, you are right, but the solution to null geodesic would be the same as the one given above, wouldn't it?

Comment: A null geodesic requires that your $c_1$ be equal to  $\pm c_0$ times your $c_3$ so $x=\pm c_0t+const.$